# One of our drupal themes is causing safari to display a security popup warning

Tags: theming

Attached are screenshots of the popup.

[image][image]

Only displayed for a particular theme. This is kinda tricky for me to debug because, I use a PC.

My client reported this error to me.

He says it only happens when that one particular theme is the active theme.

Can someone shed the light here? What are the possible reasons that would trigger this popup message on safari? It will help me know what and on which files to look.

Thank you :)

Comment: Without knowing more about the theme, no-ones really going to be able to help you with this.  Does the theme call any extra code in any of the template?  Any dodgy JavaScript?

Comment: Does that page have a login for on it?  If so, do other pages without a login form also cause it?

Comment: Hi, yes the login form is the culprit. Every page has that. Thanks